# how to change the wallpaper using OC or Swift on mac

Tags: swift

how to change the wallpaper using OC or Swift on mac？

Use OC or swift to set wallpaper，Who knows how to do it？

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set NSImage or NSData as Desktop Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041034/how-to-set-nsimage-or-nsdata-as-desktop-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gan get all the screens from this code:

```
let screens = NSScreen.screens
```

And set wallpaper By This code

```
let newWallpaperURL = URL(/* ... */)
for i in screens {
 try! NSWorkspace.shared().setDesktopImageURL(newWallpaperURL, for: i, options: [:])
}
```